# Интеграция JUnit тестов в билд скрипт Ant

Tags: java, ant, junit, юнит-тесты

Добавляю в ant билд скрипт прогонку юнит тестов JUnit. Создал таргет:

```
<!-- Run the JUnit Tests -->
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="no">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${junit.dir}" includes="junit-4.10.jar"/>
    </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${unittest.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest> 
    </junit>
</target>
```

но получаю ошибку для всех тестов вот с таким текстом:

```
Testsuite: Application.Enums.Timeline.TrackLabelsTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec

    Caused an ERROR
Application.Enums.Timeline.TrackLabelsTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Application.Enums.Timeline.TrackLabelsTest
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
```

Судя по всему, он не может найти сам тест, верно? Не могу разобраться, нужно ли в таргете компиляции компилировать и папку с тестами, тоесть ${unittest.dir} ? Как он конкретно работает - компилирует все java-файлы в папке ${unittest.dir} по **/*.java этому типу (тоесть все), и запускает на выполнение JUnit тест?

Дебаг лог Анта тоже ничего интересного не дал.

Comment: если мне не изменяет память, в таком варианте как вы сейчас запускаете тест, вам не надо компилировать ничего просто указываете папку с исходниками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо включить тесты в `classpath` и компилировать их

Comment: Скомпилировал, класспас превратился вот в это:
<classpath>
  <fileset dir="${junit.dir}" includes="junit-4.10.jar"/>
  <fileset dir="${unittest.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
</classpath>
но пока безрезультатно(

Comment: Получилось! :)
<classpath>
<fileset dir="${junit.dir}" includes="junit-4.10.jar"/>
<pathelement  location="${build.dir}"/>
</classpath>
Добавил в класспас путь к сбилжденым классам :)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге вот что получилось:

```
<!-- Run the JUnit Tests -->
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="no">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${junit.dir}" includes="junit-4.10.jar"/>
        <pathelement  location="${build.dir}"/>
    </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${unittest.dir}" />
        </batchtest> 
    </junit>
</target>
```

[http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/216217/how-to-use-java-to-call-ant-junit-target#](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/216217/how-to-use-java-to-call-ant-junit-target) - этот ресурс хорошо помог в сумме с ответом Barmaley :)